# SQL string from an HQL query?

Tags: hibernate, hql

HQL queries are converted to SQL.

I would like my program to have the complete SQL string before it is sent to my database.

Can I do this?

---

*Notes:*

I can see the SQL sent to the database by setting

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

in my cfg.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can create a class that implements `org.hibernate.Interceptor`, register it with `Configuration.setInterceptor(Interceptor)` on startup, and then get access to the SQL through the `Interceptor.onPrepareStatement(String sql)` callback.

See [Interceptor javadocs](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html)